# How to make posts on my index page seperate elements for styling purposes?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My posts appear on my index page as one element.  I would like to make each individual post behave as a different element for style purposes.  (Side note: I am trying to display each post vertically, and display a border around each post)  I will post my code below.

Index view:

```
<li class="thought">
<% @thoughts.each do |f| %>
<span class="title"><%= f.title %></span>
<span class="content"><%= f.content %></span>
<span class="timestamp">
Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(f.created_at) %> ago.
</span>
<% end %>
</li>
```

Controller CSS:

```
.thought {
float: left;
display: block;
width:300px;
height:150px;
}
```

index action:

```
def index
@thoughts =  Thought.order('created_at desc')



end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put the list-item tags inside of the `each` loop:

```
<% @thoughts.each do |f| %>
  <li class="thought">
    <span class="title"><%= f.title %></span>
    <span class="content"><%= f.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(f.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I get them to display vertically?

Comment: You should now have a list of thought elements, to display them vertically you need to do some styling with CSS. If you're unsure how to accomplish that, I'd recommend you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand your intentions, but ERB + rails gives you the beauty of iterating through each of your `@thoughts`

for example you can do:

```
<% @thoughts.each do |thought| %>
   <h1 class="thought"> thought.attributes </h1>
<%end%>
```

This would result in each of your thoughts being in it's own `h1` with its own css.

Hope this helps.